# Open WeChat browser from Android / iphone app

Tags: android, ios, wechat

I have an official page in WeChat, also an in-app which is HTML5 bassed.
I also have Android and iOs application.
I want to have a button in the native application, that will launch WeChat browser with the html5 url.

I understood that in the web I can use url scheme to do it like this:
weixin://dl/businessWebview/link/?appid=%s&url=%s

is there a way to utilize same functionality in native android / ios application?